# Is there a method in speedsolving without f2l?

Tags: rubiks-cube, speedsolving

I use the beginners method to solve the Rubik's cube and solve it in 50 seconds. Is there any way to solve it without F2L?

Comment: There's an algorithm, I forget the name, where you solve the bottom two layers of the L side, the bottom two layers of the R side, then the top four corners, then only using U and Rr' moves (and their inverses) solving the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There are other methods like Petrus or Roux, but they all involve some form of block building. CFOP is the most popular method because it has a good balance of low move count and relatively small number of short and ergonomic algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!